# Jest coverage issue

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I've started to work with Jest a few days ago and I'm trying to get 100% of coverage, but I have simple issue, which I cant solve.

Here's example of Jest Coverage

```
 File          |% Stmts |% Branch |% Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |  
  src/lib      |  66.67 |       0 |     10 |      100 |                   |
   theme.js    |  66.67 |       0 |     10 |      100 |             64,81 |
```

Therefore, I found line 64 and 81. Here are simple functions for styled-components.

```
export const fontSize = (fontSize, lineHeight) => (`
  font-size: ${fontSize}px;
  line-height: ${lineHeight ? `${lineHeight}px` : '1.1'}; // that's 64
`);

export const gradient = (gradType, gradDirection, gradStart, gradEnd) => (`
  background: ${gradType}-gradient(${gradType === 'linear' ? gradDirection+',' : ''} ${gradStart}, ${gradEnd}); // that's 81
`);
```

How can I test them? I tried this, but still got information that 64 and 81 uncovered.

```
const grad = {
      gradType: 'linear',
      gradDirection: 'toTop',
      gradStart: '#000000',
      gradEnd: '#ffffff',
    };

expect(`background:${grad.gradType}-gradient(${grad.gradType === 'linear' ? grad.gradDirection+',' : ''}${grad.gradStart},${grad.gradEnd});`)
      .toEqual(`background:linear-gradient(toTop,#000000,#ffffff`);`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to test your function, you have to call it :

```
// theme.test.js
const { fontSize } = require('./theme');

expect(fontSize('size', 'height')).toBe(`
  font-size: sizepx;
  line-height: heightpx; // that's 64
`);

 expect(fontSize('size', null)).toBe(`
  font-size: sizepx;
  line-height: 1.1; // that's 64
`);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I get it!